# SQLite How to randomly select minimum values for all cases?

Tags: sqlite

I want to randomly select a row from a table where multiple minimum values can exist in the column Number. For example I have a Table containing Titles, Numbers and Categories like so:

Ti Nu Ca

A  0  c7

W  0  c7

Y  0  c7

C  0  c9

H  3  c9

This query will return a random row where Number equals 0 AND Ca equals c7:
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ((Ca = 'c7') And Nu = ( SELECT min(Nu) FROM Table )) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;

But when the Table contains:

Ti Nu Ca

A  3  c7

W  1  c7

Y  5  c7

C  0  c9

H  3  c9

The above query does not return anything. I would expect the row "W 1 c7" being returned. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-query looks like it was always matching Nu = 0 regardless of what Ti was, and since there is no row where Nu = 0 and Ca = "c7", it returns nothing. You'll probably need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] x
WHERE Ca = 'c7' And Nu = (SELECT min(Nu) FROM [Table] where x.Ca = Ca)
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

If you add another row containing Ti="Z", Nu=1, Ca="c7" then you should see the Ti value flip between "W" and "Z" in the returned row.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is spot on!